# What is a proper way to add listeners to new elements after using AJAX to get the html content? (jQuery, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addeventlistener

I am making something that can loads new setting pages via AJAX, I am not sure what's the most efficient way to bind listeners to those elements from the new content page?

Here's my thought. I can make a function that compares file path, and for each condition, then I will apply correct listeners to those new elements based on what page that AJAX loaded. I feel like it will makes the function so big if I have a large amount of pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: What you described as your thought is essentially how it's handled in JQM if you're using a global script, you'd just listen for a pageinit with a specific id. Yes, it can get large. For events that are common to all pages, you can save coding by using event delegation.

Answer (score 17):

Two ways:

1) Bind on a non-dynamic parent container using `.on()`

```
$('.some-parent-class').on('click', '.element', function() {
  // DO STUFF!
});
```

2) Bind the new elements after ajax call is completed

```
$.ajax(url, {
  // ajax options
}).done( function(data) {
  var newEl = $('<div class="element"></div>');
  // Setup your newEl with data here...
  newEl.on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
  });
  newEl.appendTo($('.some-parent-class'));
});
```

The former usually results in quicker ajax response times, but **may** also slow click responsiveness down.

Comment: Your second example is weird. What happens when there are existing `.element` elements (like from previous AJAX requests)? You bind two events. That selector should be more specific (or only be applied to the response from the AJAX request)

Comment: it's a general case.. you can put in a more specific selector if you want

Comment: Yeah, I think that's great :)

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `.done(function(data){ $('.element', data).click(function(){ }); });`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy depends on what you want to do with it :x, and what data is returned from the ajax call

Comment: But O.P. said, `I am not sure what's the most efficient way to bind listeners to those elements from the new content page`. And since you're answering OP's question, you should address that correctly in my book.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Very possible. There's several options obviously with what you could do with `data` and what to target to bind events

Comment: @Ohgodwhy You're quoting the OP about efficiency...so why are you binding events to `$(document)`? There's no difference with this answer's code and what you're suggesting. It's no more/less efficient

Comment: @Ian Incorrect. I'm not quoting about efficiency, I'm quoting about working with returned data from the ajax call. `var newEl = $('<div class="element"></div>');` does not work with any returned data, where as, `$('.element', data)` selects from the returned set of data. Moreover, without being able to see what the HTML markup is, I have no way of knowing what closer static parent element exists. I'm merely trying to ensure the question is answered appropriately, because, if I used this, I'd assume that I have to create a new element within the done function, and not leverage elements returned

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Your comment said "But O.P. said, `I am not sure what's the most efficient way`. Anyways, `$('.element', data)` doesn't work when `data` is JSON. Populus just provided the basic setup for how to handle this. Maybe they need to loop over everything in `data` and append an element to something like Populus' `newEl` they set up. You're right though, it could probably be explained better so some things aren't assumed

Comment: if you're worried about efficiency binding on `$(document)` is far from efficient as the event has to bubble all the way up the entire tree of dom elements before it executes.

Comment: binding on `$(document)` may also be incorrect as you may have an intermediate element that did `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery's .[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle event delegation. The first element you supply is a static element (never removed / replaced). the first argument is the event you wish to delegate against, mouseover/click, etc. The 2nd argument is the element we wish to have the event fire on when the event occurs. The 3rd argument is the callback, which is the function to run when the event fires.

```
$(document).on('event', 'elementIdentifier', function(){
    //your code
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is a perfect illustration @Ian

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".parent-div").on("click", ".child-div-class-name" ,function(){
  somefunction();
});
```

all the new inserted elements inside the `.parent-div` will be having the listeners `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Populus' answer, which is great as it is, a logically equivalent solution to his second option would be to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```
     var iGotYou = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        $.ajax({
             //ajax paramaters
        })
            .done(function( data ) {
                //handle the data as necessary...
                //then resolve the Promise
                res();
            });
    });

    //the Promise has been resolved
    iGotYou.then(function (response) {
        //add the event listener now that the promise has been fulfilled
       document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        //whatever you want to do on click event
       });
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but you can use jQuery's .on() function to bind to elements that already exist in your document, OR elements that will exist in the future.

Here's a quick example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#new-button', function() {
        alert("You clicked the new button");
    });

    //get some HTML via ajax. Let's assume you're getting <button id="new-button">Click me</button>
    $.get('url', function(res) {
        $('body').append(res);
    });
});
```